# Is it raining in/at/on Stephen's Green?

Tags: prepositions

There is a park in Dublin called St Stephen's Green. Which prepositions of place would you use (and what context would you use them in) in the sentence "It's raining ... Stephen's Green"?

Comment: It generally rains *in* a city, but *on* a park or other relatively small and well-circumscribed property, at least in the US.

Comment: All three can be correct; it depends on whether you want to indicate that Stephen's Green is an area, a location, or a surface.

Comment: Choster, these were my thoughts, if you find some time could you elaborate?

Comment: @choster You know what it is; it's a park. The OP said so. The normal prep is "in".

Comment: @BillJ- But it's not a park- it's a *green*.  (I know greens look kinda like parks).  But it's always "a concert on the green" not "a concert in the green".

Comment: @Jim It is a PARK that happens to be called St Stephen's Green. The OP said so.

Comment: @BillJ But Jim seems to know the place. And if concerts are always held *on the Green* - then it seems reasonable for it to *rain on the Green*. In the same way it *rains on the terrace, or on the balcony*. And although it *rains **at** Wembley Stadium*, *it rains **on** the pitch*.

Comment: @BillJ I think we would need to defer to local knowledge here. Does it rain *in St Stephen's Green* or *on St Stephen's Green*? I'm beginning to see the point of the OP's question. It certainly *rains on Wimbledon Common*.

Comment: @WS2 Yes, me too. I'd say that "It's raining on The Green" but "It's raining in St Stephen's Park". Strange isn't it?

Comment: @BillJ Perhaps we should start thinking about how the sun shines! Oh no....please!

Comment: @WS2  Lol ! Oh well, it's 'beer o'clock' here. Cheers!

Comment: @BillJ I am perfectly aware that St Stephen's Green is a park. Raining *in* Yosemite is different from raining *at* Yosemite is different from raining *on* Yosemite, too, and they all have legitimate uses.

Answer (score 7):

The position in Britain would be as follows:

If *St Stephen's Green* was, let's say, a village on the Yorkshire Dales (or village, town or city anywhere) it would either be *in* or *at*. The larger the place the more likely it is to be *in* I believe. One would be unlikely to hear *Is it raining at London/Paris/New York ?* etc.

If *St. Stephen's Green* was a street, or a square in London, let's say, it would almost always be *in* (though it could be *at*). However if it was a very large and important street, one might use *on*. *Is it raining on Knightsbridge/Piccadilly/Bayswater Road?* would be perfectly usual. One might also ask of someone on a journey *Is it raining on the M4 motorway?*

If *St. Stephen's Green* was a large city park - it would be *in*. *Is it raining in Hyde Park?*. However if it was a very large expanse of open country one could use *on*. *Is it raining on Hampstead Heath?* for example. Though if it's a forest it would be *in*. *It is raining in Epping Forest*. But open country would always be *on*. *It is raining on Dartmoor/the Salisbury Plain* etc. In counties or regions it is always *in*; *raining in the Peak District/the West Country/Somerset* etc. Although it does rain *on the Norfolk Broads*.

If *St Stephen's Green* was a railway or London Tube station - I think it would almost always be *at*.

**To answer the very specific question about *St Stephen's Green* in Dublin - if it is what I suspect, a city park - it would almost certainly be *in*. However if it is a very large expanse of country it would most likely be *on*. It would not be *at***.

**However this question may only be answerable with reference to local knowledge. If, as has been mentioned by one commenter, that they hold *Concerts on the Green* (at St Stephens Green), then I don't see why it could not rain *on St Stephen's Green*. It certainly rains *on Clapham Common***

I hadn't realised, until I began to think about this, how nuanced it all is. But it is the sort of thing that picks out native speakers from otherwise fluent speakers. Choice of prepositions also picks out Americans from British, in a very big way.

Comment: We get more practice hereabouts.

Comment: @WS2 Are you seriously saying that "It's raining on Yorkshire" is idiomatic? It's raining in the Lake District / The Chilterns etc. is the norm. Only with a some non-name areas like the moors, for example, would one say "It's raining on the moors"

Comment: @BillJ No - you will notice I have said it rains ***in*** counties, and *in* places like the Peak District - but *on* moors, and *on the Broads*. Or, as I see you are a Surrey man, *on the North Downs*.

Comment: @WS2 "Raining on Knightsbridge". Come on!

Comment: @BillJ  **Could be** *on*, though not necessarily. It would definitely be *raining on the M25*, or the North or South Circular.

Comment: WS2 Yes, that's true. But the M25 is not a place name. You don't live in/on the M25. Which is why I made the point about "in" being the norm for countries, towns, cities. Oh well ...

Comment: @BillJ Yes I agree with you as regards counties.

Comment: @BillJ I think that's why one member close-voted the question for ***primarily-opinion-based***. It's not me. I think WS2 is trying to cover as much as possible +1)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, all three can be correct - it simply depends on what you're attempting to say, and how you're viewing "St Stephen's Green". (disclaimer - I'm an American.)

**"raining on St Stephen's Green"** - This is expressing the concept that raindrops are hitting the physical substance of St Stephen's Green. That is, "St Stephen's Green" is the actual grass/earth/pavement, and rain is falling on that physical thing.

**"raining in St Stephen's Green"** - This is expressing the concept that "St Stephen's Green" is a geographic area with extent - more specifically that there is a three dimensional space which can be labeled "St Stephen's Green", and that rain is occurring within that volume. The volumetric aspect of the green can be a little fuzzy, given that there isn't necessarily a defined "top" to it, but at some point you go from "birds were flying in St Stephen's Green" to "planes were flying over St Stephen's Green".

Even if you're thinking about "St Stephen's Green" as a two dimensional extent - for example, a region on a map - "in" may be appropriate if you're also thinking about the rain occurring in that same two dimensional context. For example, a TV weather forecaster with very detailed forecasts might point to the weather map and the storm clouds icons within the boundaries and say "today it will rain in St Stephen's Green".

**"raining at St Stephen's Green"** - This is expressing the concept that "St Stephen's Green" is a location without geographical extent. That is, "St Stephen's Green" is a point location and rain is occurring in a region nearby.

Note that the choice of preposition doesn't necessarily have to do with the intrinsic nature of the location, but more with how you're conceptualizing the space. "The naughty child was playing in Piccadilly Circus." but "I'll meet you at Piccadilly Circus." and "Protesters drew graffiti on Piccadilly Circus.": you go from Piccadilly Circus being a space within which people can exist, to a single location where two people can meet, to physical surface which can be painted.

Certainly the type of location would influence the choice - larger areas would more likely be an "in" than an "at", for example, being harder to conceptually reduce to a single point. Frequency of usage also tends to make certain pairs sound better than others. But intrinsically the choice of preposition is contingent on how that space is conceptualized, rather than any innate nature of the space.

Answer (score 0):

I'd put *St Stephen's Green* (lowly that it may be when compared to major cities!) in the same category as any other place:

It's raining **in** *London*/ *Canterbury*/ *New York*/ *Manhattan*/ *Italy*/ *Rome*/ *St Stephen's Green.*